# performSelectorInBackground: on main thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I know this is a wack question, but it is valid to performSelectorInBackground: on an iPhone apps' main thread? I am aware of performSelectorOnMainThread: but I was just wondering if performSelectorInBackground: can also be used on the main thread. My understanding is it cannot, because performSelectorInBackground: spawns a new thread each time.

Answer (score 2):

`performSelectorInBackground:` essentially spawns a new thread, then performs the desired selector on that thread.

So, no it does not execute on the main thread. Ever.

I think that using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` without a delay would be appropriate for your situation, because that *does* perform the selector on the main thread, except that it's performed in the next iteration of the current run loop:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```